Java 6 library - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
I have to process JSON response in a Java 1.6 project without any library manager (can't use Maven). So, in order to do so, I chose Jackson 2.6.7 (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.6.7.x) that can be used with Java 6.
I downloaded core, annotations and databind jars from here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.7/ but, when I import those jars into my project and start it I get "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0".
I thought those jars were built with Java 8, so I downloaded the source jars, unpacked them, compiled and built the jar again di Java 6: same result.
It feels like I'm missing something, how do can I build those libraries to run on a Java 6 project?

it's still using Java 8 somewhere

You can check the version of the classes with javap. Are you sure you're using a java 6 compiler? You can set the output with source and target arguments.

@Stultuske your comment is not constructive nor does help in any way.

@matt Yea, I used javap on a random class to check the major version and it is 50, Java 6

@ayyylmao it explains what is going wrong. either way, you should never just assume you can take a library, re-compile it in whatever version you want, and not expect side-effects. that library likely still has a dependency of it's own, on a Java 8 compiled code base. You say my comment doesn't help, I beg the differ. the problem is: you don't seem to understand it

When you run your program, you're including a class on the classpath that is java 8. How are you running your program? Which IDE are you using? Maybe you need to tell your ide to clean up everything and start over because you have a lingering java 8 class.

@Stultuske i do seem to understand it, you don't seem to understand the question. If you look at the libraries i linked, they are compatible with Java 6.

@ayyylmao YOU yourself claim that you still get that identical error message. So, either in one of those libraries, or somewhere in your code, you are still using classes that have been compiled using Java 8, or you would not have gotten that error.
